# How to implement word by word undo/redo in UIWebview injected by javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, undo-redo

I am developing an app which has rich text editor feature. On top of [ZSSRichTextEditor](https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor) I have written my editor code. Here my editor is UIWebView which will be injected by javascript code to support/edit the rich text content.

[ZSSRichTextEditor](https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor) has undo/redo feature but it does not comply with my requirement.

**Requirement** : I want to use feature undo/redo word by word rather then line by line, anyone have any idea how can i do that?

There are so many examples to implement undo/redo in `UITextView` using `NSUndoManager` but is there any way for `UIWebView` by witch i can do word by word undo/redo?